# Angular 2 Interceptor map never called

Tags: angular, httpclient, interceptor

i just migrate from angular 2 `Http` to `HttpClient` to use HttpInterceptor, 
my interceptor look likes:

```
return next.handle(request).map(event => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        if (event.ok) {
            return event.body.data;
        } else {
            throw new Error(event.body.statusCode);
        }
    }
});
```

and somewhere in my service i use httpClient like:

```
this._httpClient.get(url).map(data => { 
    console.log('I never called');
    return data.foo; 
});
```

and `subscribe` inside my component like:

```
this._barservice
  .getFooData()
  .subscribe(
    foo => {
      console.log(foo);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

but `map` function inside service never get called!

Comment: and you are subscribing where?

Comment: @Alex sorry, updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the `HttpResponse` as is, the condition `if (event instanceof HttpResponse)` already checks if it's a successful request. To catch any potential errors, you should use `catch` and check for `HttpErrorResponse`:

```ts
return next.handle(request).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    return event;
  }
}).catch(err => {
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    return Observable.throw(err)
  }
})
```

Remember to import `HttpErrorResponse` :)

Comment: i want to export `event.body.data` for every request and pass it to httpClient with Interceptor. is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with `event.body.data`? Right now it returns the JSON, what are you looking for?